# WPF Combobox with only one item

Tags: wpf, combobox

How can I show a WPF combobox with only one item differently? When there is only one item, having the possibility to select an element doesn't make sense. Therefore we would like to display only that item, instead of the combobox.

In other words, the combobox should be hidden and the first item should be displayed when there is only one item in the source collection.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a `Style` with a `DataTrigger` that sets the `Template` property to a custom `ControlTemplate` when there is only a single item in the `ComboBox's` `Items` collection:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ComboBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Items.Count, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                                <ContentControl Content="{Binding Items[0], RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ComboBox}}" />
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Style>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: @TWT: Did you try this?